# Input from Dynamically added text fields are not getting through to the request()->validate() array

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have a form where the user enters their education from Elementary to College. If they want to add any other studies they've done, they can click the "Add Other Studies" button, and a new set of input fields will appear for Other Studies

```
 {{-- Button --}}
<tr>
        <td scope="col"><button type="button" onclick="addOtherStudies()" name="add-educ-exp" id="ar-educexp" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add Other Studies</button></td>
</tr>
 {{-- Add Other Studies section --}}
 {{-- .d-none is display:none --}}
 <tr  class="d-none" id="otherStudiesRow">
          <th scope="row"><label for="other">Other Studies</label>
                    <input type="text" name="otherStudies[0]other_studies_name"/>
                    Degree/Major:<input type="text" name="otherStudies[0]other_studies_degree_major" placeholder="Masters Degree, Doctorate, Associate$quos, etc." />
          </th>
            <td>
                   <input type="text" style="width: auto; margin-top: 2rem;" name="otherStudies[0]other_studies_year"/><label for="units">If not complete, enter no. of units taken:</label><input type="text" style="width: auto;" name="otherStudies[0]other_studies_units" cols="10"/>
          </td>
           <td><textarea name="otherStudies[0]other_studies_awards" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></td</tr>
                                <tr class="d-none" id="otherStudiesbuttons">
                                    <td><button type="button" onclick="addEducation()" name="add-educ-exp" id="ar-educexp" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add Education</button></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove-input-field">Delete</button></td>

                                </tr>
```

I used the Javascript `classList` property to display/hide the set of input fields whenever needed
dynamicAddRemove.js :

```
function addOtherStudies(){
    var section = document.getElementById("otherStudiesRow");
    var buttons = document.getElementById("otherStudiesbuttons");

        section.classList.remove("d-none");
        buttons.classList.remove("d-none");

}
```

However, when I click the button and add in my data, the values in the input fields don't get forwarded to the request()->validate() array:
This is my controller:

```
        $validatedEducExp = request()->validate([
            //education start at 0, length 12
            "elementary_name" => ['nullable','required_with:elementary_year,elementary_awards','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            "elementary_year" => ['nullable','required_with:elementary_name,elementary_awards',new fromToYearRule],
            "elementary_awards" => ['nullable','required_with:elementary_name,elementary_year','string'],
            "highschool_name" => ['nullable','required_with:highschool_year,highschool_awards','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            "highschool_year" => ['nullable','required_with:highschool_name,highschool_awards',new fromToYearRule],
            "highschool_awards" => ['nullable','required_with:highschool_name,highschool_year','string'],
            "college_name" => ['nullable','required_with:college_year,college_awards,degree,college_completed,college_awards','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            "college_year" => ['nullable','required_with:college_name,college_awards,degree,college_completed,college_awards',new fromToYearRule],
            "degree" => ['nullable','required_with:college_name,college_year,college_awards,college_completed,college_awards','alpha','min:4','max:100'],
            "college_completed"=> ['nullable','required_with:college_name,college_year,college_awards,degree,college_awards'],
            "college_units" => ['nullable','digits_between:1,2'],
            "college_awards" => ['nullable','required_with:college_name,college_year,college_awards,degree,college_completed','required_with:elementary_name,elementary_year','string'],

            //other studies start at 12, length 5
            'otherStudies.*.other_studies_name' => ['max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            'otherStudies.*.other_studies_degree_major' => ['alpha','min:4','max:100'],
            'otherStudies.*.other_studies_year' =>  [new fromToYearRule],
            'otherStudies.*.other_studies_units' => ['digits_between:1,2'],
            'otherStudies.*.other_studies_awards' => ['string'],

            //exams start at 17, length 3
            'Exams.*.exam_name' => ['nullable','required_with: exam_grade,exam_date','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            'Exams.*.exam_grade' => ['nullable','required_with: exam_name,exam_date','digits_between:1,3'],
            'Exams.*.exam_date' =>  ['nullable','required_with: exam_date,exam_name','before_or_equal: today','date'],

            //work exp starts at 20 length 6
            'workExps.*.from' => ['nullable','digits:4'],
            'workExps.*.to' => ['nullable','digits:4'],
            'workExps.*.salary' =>  ['nullable','numeric'],
            'workExps.*.employer_name_address' => ['nullable','max:255','string'],
            'workExps.*.position' => ['nullable','min:5','max:50', new LetterSpaceOnly],
            'workExps.*.reason_for_leaving' =>  ['nullable','string',new LetterSpaceOnly],

            //seminar starts at 26,3
            'Seminars.*.title' => ['nullable','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            'Seminars.*.date' => ['nullable','before_or_equal: today','date'],
            'Seminars.*.conducted_by' =>  ['nullable','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],

            //skills starts 29, 2
            'languages' => ['nullable','max:255',new CommaSpace],
            'hobbies_skills' =>  ['nullable','max:255',new CommaSpace],

            //others info starts 31, length 3
            'blood_type' => ['nullable'],
            'health_problems' => ['nullable', 'max:255',new CommaSpace],
            'convictions' => ['nullable', 'max:255','string']
        ]);
```

When I enter information in the otherStudies input fields and do a `ddd()` when save button is clicked, only this appears, and `otherStudies` array can't be found:

```
array:19 [▼
  "elementary_name" => null
  "elementary_year" => null
  "elementary_awards" => null
  "highschool_name" => null
  "highschool_year" => null
  "highschool_awards" => null
  "college_name" => null
  "college_year" => null
  "degree" => null
  "college_units" => null
  "college_awards" => null
  "languages" => null
  "hobbies_skills" => null
  "blood_type" => null
  "health_problems" => null
  "convictions" => null
  "Exams" => array:1 [▶]
  "workExps" => array:1 [▶]
  "Seminars" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

However, when I go back to the page, the entered  information gets retained in the `otherStudies` field due to the `old()` helper, meaning the information is saved to the session, correct? But is not able to move forward to the validate() function. What's going on?

Comment: IDs MUST be unique so where are you cloning the studies? If this is a JavaScript issue of adding elements, then please post a [mcve]  using the `[<>]` snippet editor WITHOUT your templating, so only HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Change your name of input to

```
otherStudies[0][other_studies_name]
otherStudies[0][other_studies_degree_major]
```